# How to remove a list of words from beginning of a sentence

Tags: php

I have a list of words to remove from beginning of a sentence.

With this code i am able to remove only 1 word from the beginning of string, in this example the word 'Hello'

```
    for($i=0; $i<strlen(string); $i++){
    $remove = 'Hello';
    if (substr(string, 0, strlen($remove)) == $remove) {
    string = substr(string, strlen($remove));}
    string=ucfirst(string);}

 input :Hello World.
 output:World.
```

how to modify this code and add a list of words to remove using the code once? maybe an array of words will be great.

Also im able to use this code several times for each word that i have to remove but in terms of performance i think will peform slow. any help? thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try to use PHP preg_replace function.

```
$string = 'Hello world Hello';

$patterns = array();
$patterns[0] = '/Hello/';

$replacements = array();
$replacements[0] = '';

ksort($patterns);
ksort($replacements);

echo preg_replace($patterns, $replacements, $string, 1);
```

reference: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php

Comment: i want to remove only the first word of sentence.

Answer (score 0):

I would explode the string into an array.

```
$string = 'these are words some of which may be bad like this1 this2 and this3';

$words = explode(' ', $string);

foreach($words as $word) {

   // Insert function to check your list of words against an array remove
   // and even replace them with your own.
   // View: preg_replace http://us2.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php

}
```